# Decrypt incoming HTTPS traffic in Node https server

Tags: node.js, encryption, https

Say I have a Node `https` server set up like so:

```
var https = require('https'),
    fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/path/to/cert.pem"),
  key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/path/to/key.pem")
};

https.createServer(options, function(req, res){
  res.writeHead(200);

  var body = "";

  req.on('data', function(chunk){
    var body += chunk;
  });

  req.on('end', function(){
    console.log(body); // garbled/encrypted text
  });
});
```

The body would just be an encrypted request. How would I decrypt this so it's readable?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the `https` module automatically takes care of that. The request was gzipped, I didn't notice until later. Made a stupid mistake.